# Qt5 - Windows: VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll was not found

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, qt5

I am about to deploy a small application on `Windows 10`. I successfully build and run the application and created the executable file thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271296/qt5-windows-windows-cannot-find-executable). 
The problem I have is that all of a sudden there is a missing `.dll`. And to be specific the error message after clicking on the `.exe` to make sure the application was working to my surprise was the one below:

**VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll was not found**

[image: error]

In my debug folder I have the `.exe` created and had no idea why was asking for that library.

here is my `.pro` file:

```
QT += quick quickcontrols2 concurrent network core gui

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

TARGET = SMTPEmail
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += SMTP_BUILD
#win32:CONFIG += dll

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        progressbardialog.cpp \
        robot.cpp \
        robotmanager.cpp \
        settings/emailaddress.cpp \
        settings/mimeattachment.cpp \
        settings/mimecontentformatter.cpp \
        settings/mimefile.cpp \
        settings/mimehtml.cpp \
        settings/mimeinlinefile.cpp \
        settings/mimemessage.cpp \
        settings/mimemultipart.cpp \
        settings/mimepart.cpp \
        settings/mimetext.cpp \
        settings/quotedprintable.cpp \
        settings/smtpclient.cpp \
        user.cpp \
        usermanager.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    progressbardialog.h \
    robot.h \
    robotmanager.h \
    settings/SmtpMime \
    settings/emailaddress.h \
    settings/mimeattachment.h \
    settings/mimecontentformatter.h \
    settings/mimefile.h \
    settings/mimehtml.h \
    settings/mimeinlinefile.h \
    settings/mimemessage.h \
    settings/mimemultipart.h \
    settings/mimepart.h \
    settings/mimetext.h \
    settings/quotedprintable.h \
    settings/smtpclient.h \
    settings/smtpexports.h \
    user.h \
    usermanager.h
```

**What have I done so far**

**1)** In order to solve this last problem I researched and came across [this useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341213/difference-between-vcruntime140d-app-dll-and-vcruntime140d-dll/42348911#42348911) which also explained the main difference. Although the thing to be noted is that this application will run on Desktop only.

**2)** I found this version to download [vcruntime140_app.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/vcruntime140_app.dll.html) from which I downloaded the missing library. Unzipped and added to my debug folder as also possible to see from below print screen:

[image: debug-folder]

After that I built and run the application but surprisingly I was getting the same exact error despite missing `.dll` was manually added to the debug folder.

**3)** I did more research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285591/qt-missing-dll-after-deploy), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341213/difference-between-vcruntime140d-app-dll-and-vcruntime140d-dll/42348911#42348911) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306355/qt5-8-0-missing-vcruntime140d-app-dll). But all of them together didn't help me figure out how to understand what the problem was.

**4)** I tried to install this version too [vcruntime140d.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/vcruntime140d.dll.html) from the same site at point 2) above, but still the same result. Missing library `VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll was not found`

[image: error]

Last thing I have to notice is that: I downloaded and tried **vcruntime140_app.dll** then **vcruntime140d.dll** but I am not able to find a **vcruntime140d_app.dll** if it exists.

I don't understand why, despite the library is there as is possible to see also here `C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\build-signalsQML-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug\vcruntime140_app.dll` the double click on the executable still give the same error.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204009/discussion-on-question-by-emanuele-qt5-windows-vcruntime140d-app-dll-was-not).

Comment: From the file names, it looks like you’re trying to deploy a debug build (it doesn’t work properly, and I think it’s also legally not allowed). Did you try with a release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to deploy QT dependencies to application folder. After trying a lot, following command solved the issue for me.

C:\Qt\5.12.10\msvc2017_64\bin>windeployqt.exe Project path\Release

This command copies all the required QT dependencies to application folder.

Got the hint from the following link:
[QT forum reference](https://forum.qt.io/topic/118052/visual-studio-2019-qt-c-executable-file-not-working/4)